# Чтение из Cookie

Tags: php

Значит есть такой код.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['mypages'])) {
    header('Location: (переадресация на друг страницу)');
} else {
    $visit = "active";
    setcookie("mypages", $visit, time() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60, $mycook);
}
```

Захожу в браузер смотрю куки, всё записалось, всё отлично, куки есть, параметр есть, однако `$_COOKIE['mypages']` при следующем входе ничего не видит. И мол кука не найдена.

Comment: А какое значение принимает `$mycook`?

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: А попробуйте без него.

Comment: И в прям из-за этого, только не могу понять по какой причине, это ведь параметр тот который надо в куки всё пишет как это связано с чтением не пойму..

Comment: Просто `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` содержит имя хоста, а не путь по нему, в документации сказано что 4-ый параметр это путь, для которого потом будет выдаваться кука.

P.S. Не забудте принять ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация на [setcookie](http://ru.php.net/setcookie), согласно ей лучше всего сделайте `$mycook = '/';`

```
<?php
define("cookie_name",'mypages');

if (isset($_COOKIE[cookie_name])) {
    header('Location: (переадресация на друг страницу)');
}
else {
    setcookie(
        cookie_name,            // Имя куки
        'active',               // значение
        time() + (7*24*60*60),  // время жизни
        '/',                    // путь
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']   // домен
    );
}
```

Но в данном примере имя хоста можно опустить, данный режим используется когда у вас куча поддоменов